# Order of rows in DataFrame after aggregation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I've got a data frame `df` (created from a hard-coded array for tests)

```
+----+----+---+
|name|  c1|qty|
+----+----+---+
|   a|abc1|  1|
|   a|abc2|  0|
|   b|abc3|  3|
|   b|abc4|  2|
+----+----+---+
```

I am grouping and aggregating it to get `df1`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as sf

df1 = df.groupBy('name').agg(sf.min('qty'))
df1.show()
+----+--------+
|name|min(qty)|
+----+--------+
|   b|       2|
|   a|       0|
+----+--------+
```

What is the expected order of the rows in `df1` ?

Suppose now that I am writing a unit test. I need to compare `df1` with the expected data frame. Should I compare them ignoring the order of rows. What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: In a distributed system order is meaningless, so yes.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense indeed.

Comment: What if I create `set` from `df1.collect()` to compare it with `expected` set ?

Comment: it's possible, but that's not spark related anymore then

Comment: Right. It's more a  generic python question.

Comment: you can sort by your key to make sure the list is sorted as expected for your test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ordering of the rows in the dataframe is not fixed. There is an easy way to use the expected Dataframe in test cases

Do a dataframe diff .  For scala:

```
   assert(df1.except(expectedDf).count == 0)
```

And

```
   assert(expectedDf.except(df1).count == 0)
```

For python you need to replace except by subtract

From documentation:

> subtract(other)
> Return a new DataFrame containing rows in this frame but not in another frame.
>
> This is equivalent to EXCEPT in SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but `df1.except(expectedDf)` did not compile for me. I am completely new at Python. Could you elaborate on this ?